# In Internet Explorer 11 openlayers getfeatureinfo is not working

Tags: openlayers

I am using openlayers 2.13.1 and when i updated to ie11 my getfeatureinfo is no longer working. I have tried compatibility mode as well as verified that the request is being made to the server. I copied the request and pasted it into a browser window and it works.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What `getfeatureinfo`? I think you need to elaborate further ... You could provide some code to backup the question.

Comment: the problem, for me, occurs in line 77531 in OpenLayers.debug.js. In read method of OpenLayers.Format.WMSGetFeatureInfo class. The call `data = OpenLayers.Format.XML.prototype.read.apply(this, [data]);` returns null! If anyone knows why... please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely due to returning a different format than xml. The WMSGetFeatureInfo request uses loadXML and ie11 in strict mode will bury the error. Add this to your page directives

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10">
```

Comment: Perfect!! exactly what i needed. Looks like the info_format was set to "aaplication/json" not XML.

Comment: Glad to hear it, Good luck.

Comment: That´s not a solution, to force the IE to render in IE10 mode!

Comment: @marcel That is not a valid argument, it's like saying "That's not a solution because I don't like it." No need to add ! either. If you have a valid point please make it otherwise don't flame.